# contactus() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created a contact form and fields are `name, email, and dropdown`.When I am submitting a form then I a getting error but If I print(name) then it's displaying on the terminal.

> contactus() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Would you help me out with this?

**contatus.html**

```
<form action="/contactus/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-block">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="your full name" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="input-block">
    <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled>no of Year</option>
      <option value="1">1 Year</option>
      <option value="2">2 Year</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="reachEmail" class="input-block">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="Send" value="SEND">
</form>
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
from .models import contactus

def home(request):
return render(request, 'demo1/home.html', {'': ''})


def contactus_submit(request):
if request.method == "POST":
name=request.POST.get('name','')
year=request.POST.get('year','')
email=request.POST.get('email','')
contact=contactus(name=name,year=year,email=email)
contact.save();


return render(request, 'demo1/contactus.html')
```

**Model.py**

```
class contactus(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import contactus
admin.site.register(contactus)
```

Comment: try changing name of view.

Comment: I'm not an expert in those issues, but are you sure a class and a function should have the same name "contactus"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the naming conventions followed by django.

models

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST.get('name','')
        year=request.POST.get('year','')
        email=request.POST.get('email','')
        contact=Contact(name=name,year=year,email=email)
        contact.save()
        return render(request,'demo1/contactus.html')
```

Comment: Can you check it once again my code. I updated, I am getting SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: May I know what you changed?

Comment: indentation has changed, before the return was outside the function

Comment: Yes, This time it's working. Remove one more left space from return so if and return will display vertically one line. It's solved my isssue.

Answer (score 1):

```
contact=contactus(name=name,year=year,email=email)
```

This statement is trying to call your view.

Change name of view to `contact_view`.

Comment: =contactus(name=name,...... this contactus is class name or function name?

Comment: @NarenVerma contactus(name=name.. ) here you are trying to create object of class contactus, which is basically a class.